# Unity reset Oculus position when key is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am trying to create a script that will reset (to a specific location) the HMD and controller locations whenever a key is pressed for calibration reasons. I am very new to unity so all I have been able to figure out is how to get key input.

```
public class resetPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            Debug.Log("pressed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't directly change the position of the VRCamera.

Rather add a parent `GameObject` to the camera and change the position of that one instead via e.g. (assuming your script is attahced to the camera)

```
public class ResetPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 resetPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // create a new object and make it parent of this object
        var parent = new GameObject("CameraParent").transform;

        transform.SetParent(parent);
    }

    // You should use LateUpdate
    // because afaik the oculus position is updated in the normal
    // Update so you are sure it is already done for this frame
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("pressed");

            // reset parent objects position
            transform.parent.position = resetPosition - transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to edit camera and controller positions for other parts of my game. I tried the parent thing on those and it made a huge difference.

Comment: So your code only works once, if you wish to reset it again after they move for a bit it doesnt work....

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is happening instead? Unfortunately I don't own an Oculus and can't really test it but it sounds strange

Comment: The first time you press space it will set the position right, but when you walk around for a bit and press space again it will not reset you back since the transform on the parent has not changed but the transform on the camera has.

Comment: I just noted you could to it way simplier by not touching the camera position at all but only invert the parent's position on key down .. this way the Camera should result in `0,0,0` anyway (see the updated code)

Comment: -transform.position would give you an error. Since you are not referencing anything

Comment: ? what do you mean? `transform` is always referenced for each `MonoBehaviour` and refers to the `Transform` component attached to the same GameObject. The position is a `Vector3` and using `- transform.position;` simply is the inverted `Vector3`

Comment: I edited my post with a screenshot of what your code errors. transform cannot be referenced by itself, transform is part of an object.

Comment: then your VisualStudio simply is configured wrong ... I can see that none of the Unity API is recognized correctly, like `Awake` etc .. apparently you opened the script in VisualStudio but nor from within Unity ... fix your intelisense

Comment: wait I found your two errors in the code. It should be transform (not tranform) as well you need to do transform.SetParent(parent.transform); (not transform.SetParent(parent);)

Comment: oh no you're right after I refactored I forgot to add the `transform` again after `parent` my fault!

Comment: your code works nicely now. I was just playing around with it and works for what my questions was. But the answer I posted below that has a link is designed for moving the player to certain re spawn location.